# PM2 Cluster - Connection Refused

Tags: node.js, mongoose, pm2

So I've created my first node.js application.  It works great.  It's using Express, MongoDB with Mongoose, and Bunyan for logging.  Before adding MongoDB/Mongoose it worked fine with PM2 (using "pm2 start app.js -i 4").  Since then I've added the code for MongoDB/Mongoose.

If I start my app with bin/www or "npm start" it works fine. But since adding MongoDB/Mongoose when I start my app with PM2 using the same command it's not working!

When I run "pm2 monit" or "pm2 list" everything looks perfectly fine.  All the apps show as online.  When I point my browser at localhost:3000 I just get a connection refused.

Is there some PM2 log file I should be looking at?  Why isn't it responding to web requests to port 3000 but the monitor and list show everything as working fine?

Comment: Since you are using cluster mode, you need to check Node.js and pm2 compatiblity.

https://keymetrics.io/2015/03/26/pm2-clustering-made-easy/#conclusion

Your Node.js version should be >= 0.11.x

Comment: I'm using iojs 2.3.1.  It was working just fine prior to adding mongoose and MongoDB.  I see no errors and it looks like it's running fine.  Does anyone have any idea if PM2 outputs any logs?  Could I run it in a debug mode to output some debug logs?

Comment: As an addition:  I've removed all things iojs/node/nvm/npm/etc.  I started over from scratch and only installed iojs, express and the express-generator.  I generated a sample express and tried firing up PM2 in both cluster and fork mode.  Neither one worked.  When starting with bin/www or with "npm start" it works just fine.

Comment: What did you end up doing Chromag?  We're facing a similar "PM2 up but connection refused", but we aren't using MongoDB/Mongoose.  We have node v4 and use redis and postgres npm packages.